# ImageGrab.grab(bbox()) doesn't return RGB values

Tags: python, screenshot, screen-capture

This is my code:

```py
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab


class Main:
    px = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=[799, 449, 800, 450]).load()
```

However, when I print px[0, 0] it returns me just an int, not an RGB triplet. Anyone knows why that is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this code work for you (you will need to install [MSS](https://github.com/BoboTiG/python-mss/) first):

```py
import mss

with mss.mss() as sct:
    img = sct.grab((799, 449, 800, 450))
    print(img.pixel(0, 0))
```

In my terminal:

```
$ python3 test.py                                                                     
(30, 30, 30)
```

Answer (score 0):

executing the following works for me

```
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab

def main():
    px = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=[799, 449, 800, 450]).load()
    print(px[0, 0]);

main()
```

in the terminal

```
$ python3 test.py                                                                     
(27, 29, 30)
```

Comment: Exact same code, I get only one value. Also when I look at the image type, it says mode = L, so it's not RGB. I am on Linux by the way, not sure if that changes things

Comment: By the way, if I remove the bbox parameter it does return an RGB.